# Как можно более грамотно оформить выборку из BD в laravel в зависимости ввода

Tags: php, laravel

У меня есть функция достающая список карт из базы. Нужно улучшить ее так , что бы при передаче через $request полей для поиска ( серия, номер, баланс) строился соответствующий запрос ( полей может быть и больше, через большое количество if else не вариант).

```
public function card_list(Request $request)
{
    $q = $request->input('card') ;

    $this->data['cards'] = Card::where('id', '>', 0)->paginate(15);

    return view('pages.card_list', $this->data);
}
```

Comment: Вопрос собственно в том как это грамотно реализовать в Laravel 5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так [реализовал](https://github.com/xEdelweiss/my-perfect-back-end/blob/master/app/Traits/Model/FindByRequestTrait.php) я:

```
trait FindByRequestTrait {
    public function scopeFindByRequest($query, $request = NULL)
    {
        if (is_null($request)) {
            $request = Input::all();
        }

        $findable = isset($this->findable) ? $this->findable : [];

        foreach ($request as $field => $value) {
            if (!in_array($field, $findable)) {
                continue;
            }

            // специфические условия обрабатываются отдельно
            // ... см. по линке

            // остальные вот так
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $query->whereIn($field, $value);
            } elseif (is_scalar($value)) {
                $query->where($field, '=', $value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*phpDoc и поиск по тегам удалены из примера, но есть в github'е*

В модели надо добавить новое свойство `$findable` с полями, по которым можно искать и подключить трейт:

```
class Card extends Model 
{
    use FindByRequestTrait;

    protected $findable = ['id', ...];

    // ...
}
```

Использование:

```
Card::findByRequest()->paginate(15);
```